# Using a column from a joined table in concatenate for another column using codeigniter

Tags: sql, codeigniter, join, concatenation

So I'm using codeigniter and I'm having difficulty trying to figure this out.

So I have this query that includes a joined table, then I need the ua_number column from that joined table for concatenation for the image column. The ua_number returns a value no problem but when I append it to the concatenation, it doesn't work as planned.

Here's the code

```
 $this->db
            ->select(" 
            p.promotion_id,
            p.partner_id,
            ps.ua_number as ua_number,
            description,
            start_date,
            end_date,
            date_created,
            CONCAT('https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/paychatph-assets/pcb_updates/promotions/', MD5(p.promotion_id), '/', (ps.ua_number), '.jpeg')  AS image
            ")
            ->from('promotions p')
            ->join('partners ps' , 'p.partner_id = ps.partner_id' , 'INNER');
```

Answer (score 0):

is the problem that in the concat statement you have a ' at the beginning and a " at the end? I would think they need to match inside a single statement.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add a
`pa.ua_number,`
to your select fields list? Maybe renaming it `as ua_number` broke something.